# Multiple Roles as Rolecounter for discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

Dear readers im currently try to make a Role Counter voice channel but it only works with
one role.

I want to use a array with the role ids and build the some showing in the voice channel name..

currently i have this code:

```html
module.exports = async (client) =>{
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('858804331829395477');
    setInterval(() =>{
       // const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
        let memberCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;

        roleids = [
            '858813502747181086', // Ceo
            '858817762108112927' //Bots

        ];
       
            roleids.forEach(findrole =>{
               const rolesize = guild.roles.cache.get(findrole).members;
                console.log(`Got ${rolesize.size} members with that role.`);
  
            })
    

            const rolechannel = guild.channels.cache.get('865628426392174592');
            rolechannel.setName(`Role Member: `);

           
        const userchannel = guild.channels.cache.get('865626409593864212');
        userchannel.setName(`Total Members: ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);

       console.log('Updating Member Count');
    }, 5000);
}
```

I want that is make the sum of both role ids (or more)  i have in one role 1 member and in the other one 7.. but it prints 1 and 7 cuz of the forEach Loop.

do you have any clue which function i should look into to get a role counter?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const roleMembers = new Set();
roleids.forEach(findrole =>{
    const rolesize = guild.roles.cache.get(findrole).members;
    roleMembers.set(rolesize.map(x => x.id));
})
// ...
rolechannel.setName(`Role Member: ${roleMembers.size}`);
```

This should be doing what you want if I understood you correctly.